# Background image not resizing on devices

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the background image not resizing on devices.
It looks fine when I rescale it in my laptop browser but not in the actual device.

I am using Bootstrap's .container-fluid.

This is the website: http://www.residenzacarducci.com/#/show

This is the css:

```
body {
    background: url("/images/Verona_bridge_c1825.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Cinzel Decorative, cursive;
    color: #777;
}
```

Thank you!

DESIRED OUTCOME:

[image: Desired Outcome]

ACTUAL OUTCOME:

[image: Actual Outcome]

Comment: It works on my iPhone 5

Comment: Hi Matthew, somebody told me that the background shakes on the ipad. Plus the container does not scroll on the iphone like it does on a computer screen...

Answer (score 0):

replace fixed with scroll, this should work

```
body {
    background: url("/images/Verona_bridge_c1825.jpg") no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Cinzel Decorative, cursive;
    color: #777;
}
```

Comment: Nope that did not work... Now to find the background picture I have to scroll down to the middle of the container.

Comment: Sorry for that, but I gave you that answer because that happened before to me on iPad and I solved it like that

Comment: Btw, I tried your styles now as it is on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus and it's working great, it seems you don't have issue with your styles so far on iPhone, I just wanted to let you know :)

Comment: Hi Ahmed you have to go to the next page to really see it